# aggressive adware irremovable apk on android

Tags: android, apk, adb, virus

A few days ago I received complaints from several customers who told me that "adware is installed automatically on your device Krono NET K5". I made invesigar and found a few apk on / system / app that had different permissions to the usual "rw-r - r--". I could erase the few simple steps in a shell:

`adb shell "su -c 'mount -o rw, remount /'"`

`adb shell "su -c 'rm /system/app/156.apk'"`

`adb shell "su -c 'rm /system/app/Launcher0607wxDjbOa.apk'"`

`adb shell "su -c 'rm /system/app/Sync.apk'"`

`adb shell "su -c 'rm /system/app/SettingProvider.apk'"`

(Note that a suspect name as there is a apk using the system call SettingsProvider.apk with letter s)

So far everything worked properly, however there is a apk which is the main cause of all adware and causing the discharge cone apk other battery savers, system cleaners, among others. This application is:
"/system/app/providerdown.apk" Permits "rwsr-sr-x"

I tried to remove it by the above method, I tried to change the permissions to remove it and it has not worked. I tried to install a recovery to eliminate apk thence Aroma File Manager (CWM, TWRP) MTK but this device does not support any custom recovery for devices MTK.

Any idea? Thanks in advance (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score -2):

---

I have same problem. You will have to be rooted for this, but i guess you have root because of that code you wrote, and the fact that app somehow gains root access and installs itself in system. Only thing I did to make things easier is:

1. Download Avast to your phone.
2. Download Clean Master to your phone and with Clean master make backup of your avast apk.
3. Go to your stock recovery. I used an app from google store to boot to recovery but any way is good.
4. Clean cache and do a factory reset.
5. Boot the device.
6. DO NOT CONNECT DEVICE TO ANY NETWORK.
7. Just skip all the stuff like login to your google account and other settings.
8. Find your Avast apk in the sd card and install it.
9. Turn on firewall and block all acces to TimeService-that is the name that apk uses when seen from android system.
10. Go to android system and disable time service. It is probably version 1.1.6

    You will still have malware in your device but it wont make mess anymore.
    I would like the permanent solution too.